# Cast int to byte[4] in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if anyone here knows an efficient way to cast an integer to a byte[4]? I'm trying to write an int into MemoryStream, and this thing wants me to give it bytes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) if you want to convert a primitive type to its byte representation. Just remember to make sure the endianness is correct for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there's an easy way to do this :)

Answer (score 7):

Use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) (constructed with your memory stream); it has a write method that takes an Int32.

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(someStream);
bw.Write(intValue);
bw.Write((Int32)1);
// ...
```

Answer (score 6):

- [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) will be the simplest solution to write to a stream
- [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) is most appropriate if you really want an array
- My own versions in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) (`EndianBitConverter` and `EndianBinaryWriter`) give you more control over the endianness, and also allow you to convert directly into an existing array.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do your own shifting!  Although i'd use the built in methods figured i'd throw this out there for fun.

```
byte[] getBytesFromInt(int i){
    return new byte[]{
        (byte)i,
        (byte)(i >> 8),
        (byte)(i >> 16),
        (byte)(i >> 24)
    };
}
```

Of course then you have to worry about endian.

Comment: also happens to be cross platform, the above also works in Java :)

Comment: Yeah lol, had to implement a utility class with similar code in Java so I could control byte conversion =P

Answer (score 2):

[`byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(42);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx)